# Azure Mobile Services Easy Tables - Am I On The Right Track?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm working on a simple mobile application in order to learn more about app development in general. I'm using Xamarin and C# to make a cross-platform app.

The end goal is to make a listing of users that are willing to be contacted to play golf. I want users to be able to enter their name and email address on one page, save the entries in a table using Azure SQL Database, and then display them in a list on another page in the app.

I've done some pretty extensive research on my own, but now I think it's time to get some real-life interaction to help guide me along. So here's my actual question...

It looks like the "Getting Started" tutorial [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) is close to what I want to do. But it seems like the database the app in the example uses is stored locally, whereas I want to create a table that all users will be able to access. Is following this walkthrough the right move for me? If not, what should I do instead?

Bear in mind that I'm committed to using Azure Mobile Services, so please refrain from answers suggesting I use a different platform.

Thanks guys!

Comment: I know you state that you are comitted to Azure Mobile Services. But be aware that this is the old azure container for the app-mobile communication. Azure has upgraded to a new container system on the new portal.azure.com. The new one is called Azure App Service - Mobile (a specific version of the App Service). I would recommend you to use that as this will be the platform/framework moving forward.

Comment: That's right, for new projects, we recommend that you use Azure Mobile Apps.

Answer (score 5):

If you use Azure Storage directly from the client app, then make sure you are **not** using Shared Key authentication. Otherwise, anyone could simply steal the credentials from the app and get full access to your blob account. To learn more, see [Shared Access Signatures](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/) and the SO question [Azure blob storage and security best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765026/azure-blob-storage-and-security-best-practices).

From the [official documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/):

> Exposing either of your account keys opens your account to the possibility of malicious or negligent use. Shared access signatures provide a safe alternative that allows other clients to read, write, and delete data in your storage account according to the permissions you've granted, and without need for the account key.

For new projects, you should use [**Azure Mobile Apps** instead of Azure Mobile Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-value-prop-migration-from-mobile-services/). The new service offers a number of features, and it is where all future investments will be.

For instance, there is now support for blob storage syncing along with regular offline data sync, and it uses SAS tokens to connect securely. Here's a tutorial for Xamarin.Forms: [Connect to Azure Storage in your Xamarin.Forms app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-blob-storage/). It includes a sample that you can deploy to your own Azure subscription with one click.

For your specific question, you could modify the Todo sample (or look at the more full-featured [Field Engineer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-fieldengineer/) sample) and add tables for Players and Games.

Comment: So I've spent the last two weeks configuring a Xamarin.Android app following [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/) tutorial. It wasn't until I debugged it using Visual Studio instead of Xamarin Studio that I got an error telling me that the Windows Azure Storage Account nuget package depends on an assembly (System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives) that doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile. Going back to your post, I noticed that you actually suggested using Xamarin.Forms! Can you suggest any workarounds so that I can use it anyway?

Comment: You might have a project misconfiguration, since Mono for Android has the same base .NET assemblies as Xamarin.Forms. Could you try upgrading the Storage nuget to 7.0.1-preview to see if the problem persists?  If it does, I recommend posting a new here tagged Xamarin, or on the Xamarin forums. The Storage SDK has tests that specifically run on Mono for Android.

Comment: I created the project from scratch and tried installing the 7.0.1-preview nugget, but now I'm getting an error telling me that I can't install the System.Diagnostics.Tools package that it depends on. I'll use your recommendations for my new question post so I can figure this out...

Comment: @msloan11 My mistake: you should install 7.0.1-preview into the Windows project only. For iOS and Android, keep it at 6.1.1-preview.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of offering on the Azure platform that will allow you to store your golf players. However, the page you linked to is for BLOB storage, and I would not recommend using that.

There is Azure table storage. Which is a NoSQL store on the Azure platform. It's highly scalable and schema-less, so very flexible. You can leverage the Azure SDK to read and write to it - or go REST if that's what you prefer. Check out the tutorial here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/

Then there is Azure SQL, which is SQL server offered on the Azure platform. This is a traditional relational database store, but more scalable ( since it's on the Azure Platform ). You can also use this solution, but it does require a bit of extra work, since you probably want to use an ORM like Entity Framework.

So in all - I would go for Azure table storage. It's really easy to get started with and will do what you want to do.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need!

Comment: This works, but how would you recommend that the mobile client connect to the database?  There is no service for getting a SAS token from Azure Storage, and it is a security risk to distribute your master key with your application. Table Storage is a fine solution, but you should add a Web API of some sort to actually provide the tokens to authenticated clients. One solution is to use the built-in features for Table Storage in Mobile Apps/Mobile Services, or use a custom API.

Comment: Depends on what your security requirement is. I would recommend you to open a new question for this, describing your security requirement and we'll have a look the options.

Comment: Unless the contents of the entire storage account should be editable by all users (including the schema, and any Blobs and Queues), then you absolutely need a SAS token for your mobile client. Please see [Shared Access Signatures](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/) in the Azure docs. The official recommendation of the Azure Storage team is that **it is an anti-pattern to distribute your master key with your app.** It would be like giving out your admin password to your DB.

Comment: Security requirement is actually very loose! Not storing anything close to critical. I'm simply making a public listing that anyone who downloads the app can sign up for, displaying whatever they choose to enter in a Full Name field and an Email field. @lindydonna-msft, I don't think my app will have enough users to warrant concern over the risks you've mentioned, but can you clarify what I would need to do to generate a SAS token with the app? I found a way to generate one with Azure Powershell, but would that be enough to cover what I want to do?

Comment: @lindydonna-msft - Thanks for pointing that out. I don't know how you read that into my response though. I would recommend writing an API backend that stands between the client app and the storage solution.

Comment: @JochenvanWylick That makes more sense! I was confused because you linked to a sample that didn't have any code for getting a SAS token. In my earlier comment I asked how you'd recommend to get the SAS token, but you didn't elaborate. FWIW, Azure Mobile Apps already is an API backend and has helpers for Azure Storage.

Comment: @msloan11 You could distribute a SAS token with the app, and restrict permissions to just a blob container, but anyone that has that token will still have full control to access the blob. A better solution is to use Azure Mobile Apps to get the token. Even better, just use the [Mobile Apps Storage nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Storage/1.1.157.1) and there's no need for a SAS token. You would use it in your Table Controller instead of EntityDomainManager.

Comment: Can you link me to any tutorials using that package?